# Author page based on Attribute - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.4

I am trying to make the author page based on the attribute created in Magento 2. Attribute ( author ) has allot of values, and each value is assigned on each product. I am trying to make a module and able to create an initially installed version of the Magento module but need some suggestions on how to make it based on the attribute. Here is login for a full understanding

```
Products: Digital books
list of products: ABC title, Mr hero, an American journey, health business
author: Mr Magento ( this author value is assigned when the added list of products mentioned above )

Frontend call: www.domain.com/author/mr-magento/
```

once called this URL, it must show a list of all products attached to this author attribute.

Same as that any author that is created must be accessible in the same above URL example with its own name and show list of products connected to author.

Answer (score 0):

Set author as product attribute and set values at product level

Then use extension which builds collection based on author product attribute

https://swissuplabs.com/attributes-and-brands-pages-for-magento-2.html

Comment: thank you for your response, but its not actually what i want, i want to build custom basic module, where page can show the author based on author name from URL and show list of products in the list of page. I have list of products, each already connect with author.

Comment: Create categories with names as authors names? And assign products manually? Could modify product grid with author column to make life easise. To create something custom will be a lot of work and I don't believe can be easily explained in a single SE answer

Comment: There is no category as the author's name!

I have attribute called "Author" as dropdown list and consist of pre-entered author names list, which i do assign to book product when i do enter it. I can show author name to product when detail product is opened. Thing only left is making author pages, and 1 template could solve product if we do add dynamic data based on received data for attribute from URL.

Comment: I meant create it / them. That gives you the product grouping and URL structure. You can hide categories from menu. But it sounds like any workaround isn't going to work for you. I recommend you look into hiring a dev.